# OpenCV get a copy of even rows of a Mat

Tags: opencv, rows, mat

I would like to get the even rows/cols of a mat of 3 channels, something like this:

```
A = 1 0 1 0 1 0
    1 0 1 0 1 0
    1 0 1 0 1 0

result = 1 1 1
         1 1 1
```

How to can I do this using openCV?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Mat img_object = imread(patternImageName);
Mat a;
for (int index = 0,j = 0; index < img_object.rows; index = index + 2, j++)
{
    a.row(j) = img_object.row(index);
}
```

But it throws the following exception:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in Mat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 269
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I could finally do it. Here is the solution

```
Mat img_object = imread(patternImageName);
Mat B;
for (int i = 0; i < img_object.cols; i += 2)
{
     B.push_back(img_object.col(i));
}
// now we got 1 large 1d flat (column) array with all the collected elements,
B = B.reshape(0,(img_object.cols/2));// 1 elem per channel, 3 rows.
B = B.t();          // transpose it
Mat result;
for (int i = 0; i < B.rows; i += 2)
{
     result.push_back(B.row(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse [resize()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) function:

```
resize(bigImage, smallImage, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, INTER_NEAREST);
```

resize() function will create new image, whose size is half of the original image.

INTER_NEAREST means that the values of small image will be calculated by "nearest neighbor" approach. In this specific case it means that value of pixel at position (1,2) in small image will be taken from pixel at position (2,4) in big image.

Comment: I didn't want to change anything in the image, I just wanted the even rows/cols from the image.

Comment: This is what resize do. It is creating new image that has only even rows and columns of original image. Of course this is abuse of resize function since this is not its original purpose, but if this does the trick...

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Since it's easier than my solution I will accept your answer instead of mine.

Comment: I tried both and I wonder why cv::resize works much faster than iterating through the rows...

Comment: Low level optimizations (SSE3 and the likes)

Answer (score 0):

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< A.size(); i+2)
{
    destMat.row(j) = (A.row(i));
    j++;
}
```

Comment: what is the utility of j? and why we're adding 0 to A.row(i)?

Comment: Not sure about the +0, i whipped it off something else. And the J is reflected inthe update to the code. It is for indexing the row of the destMat as you don't want to increment by 2

Comment: You should ask a new question as it is now a different problem.